# Django money - making a MoneyField in my model

Tags: django, django-models

So I've been trying to import A money field from django-money using this code

`from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField`

but every time am getting the same error `Import djmoney.models.fields" could not be resolved`

I added `djmoney` to installed apps in the settings file and I used `pip install django-money` as well but it's still giving me the same error

`django-money version: 2.1`
`django version: 3.2.7`

Comment: what is the version of python you are using ?

Comment: Try to makemigrations.

Comment: @amadousow 3.9.2

Comment: same problem here with python 3.10